# How to return count value from nestedfunction in NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a problem with NodeJS and MongoDB.

I would like to return a value from a nested function.

I tried different solutions, even some of Stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

Here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const ip = require('ip');
const assert = require('assert');

var dburl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/jsShop";

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use('/css', express.static('public/css'));
app.use('/images', express.static('public/images'));

app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', [
    'views',
    'public/products'
]);


app.get('', function(req, res) {

    res.render('index');

});

app.get('/index', function(req, res) {

    res.render('index');

});

app.get('/technik', function(req, res) {

    res.render('technik');

});

app.get('/kontakt', function(req, res) {

    res.render('kontakt');

});

app.get('/admin', function(req, res) {

    res.render('admin');

});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

    res.render('login');

});

app.get('/register', function(req, res) {

    res.render('register');

});

app.get('/products/articleoftheday', function(req, res) {

    res.render('articleoftheday');

});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    
    var checker = checkIfUserExists(req.body.email);
});


app.post('/register', function(req, res) {

    registerUser(req.body)

    /*
    var checker = checkIfUserExists(req.body.email);

    if (checker = 1) {
        // Tell the user that the account already exists.
    }
    else if (checker = 0) {
        registerUser(data);
    }
    */
});

app.post('/kontakt', function(req, res) {

    // Tell the user that the ticket has been issued and assign an ID.

});

function checkIfUserExists(data) {
    
    MongoClient.connect(dburl, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbobject = db.db("jsShop");
        
        dbobject.collection("users").find( { email : data } ).count(function (err, result) {
           
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            return result;
            
        });
        
        db.close();
    });
}

function checkCredentials(data, dbdata) {
    
}

function registerUser(data) {

    MongoClient.connect(dburl, function(err, db) {

        if (err) throw err;

        var dbobject = db.db("jsShop");

        dbobject.collection("users").insertOne(data);
        
        db.close();
    });
}

app.listen(80, function(err) {

    console.log('Server running on ' + ip.address() + ":80");

});
```

I would like to assign the return value of `checkUserExists()` to the variable `checker`, like I did in `app.post('/login')`, but I simply do not know how - I did it here kind of pseudocode, but if i do `console.log(checker)` it says undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about it:

1. Using callbacks

```
app.post("/register", function (req, res) {
  checkIfUserExists(req.body.email, (err, res) => {
    // use result here
  })
})

function checkIfUserExists(data, callback) {
  MongoClient.connect("", (err, db) => {
    // ...
    db.db().collection("users").find({ email: data }).count((err, res) => {
      // ...
      db.close((err, _) => {
        callback(err, res)
      })
    })
  })
}
```

2. Using promises (Better approach)

```
app.post("/register", async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const checker = await checkIfUserExists(req.body.email)
  }
  catch(error) {
    //...
  }
})

async function checkIfUserExists(data) {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect("")
    const result = await client
        .db()
        .collection("users")
        .find({ email: data })
        .count()
  await client.close()
  return result;
}
```

This is better because

- Errors only need to be handled once
- No callback hell